# android - How to use two xml for using screen orientation.?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a new android developer . I want to add two XML files. One for portrait screen and another for landscape. Can someone please give some steps to solve this problem?

Comment: I was going to post an answer but honestly it would be faster for you to follow the duplicate link; and you'll learn more this way too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ya tell. wanna learn more

Comment: @Karnesh_Prabhu as in a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

You Add into the Manifest file

```
 <activity
    android:name="YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: its not working @Harshit Trivedi

Comment: this is just not an answer to the question. you should provide some information on how to use the layout xml files. this only configures the activities behavior on orientation changes (restart activity or not).

Answer (score 0):

you can make different layout folders for landscape and portrait XML layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1) create a folder called layout-Land under the res folder.

2)copy all landscape xml files to that layout-Land folder with the same name.

3)Make this change to your manifest for that activity

android:configChanges="orientation"

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```